# What am i missing to run java on a fedora23 server

Tags: java, fedora

I have a fedora23 minimal install with amahi, and I am trying to install java.
Here is what I have done so far that was successful.

```
tar -xvf /home/mattkeran/server-jre-8u112-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm/
sudo mv ./jdk1.8.0_112 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_112
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/javaws" 1
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

I wasn't able to download from oracle or openjdk to the server so I used winscp to transfer the file from my pc.

At this point when I try to run

```
java -version
I get this error
-bash: java: command not found
```

Any help getting this working would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you run the java by invoking it on the full path (/usr/bin/java) ?

Comment: I did cd /usr/bin then tried variations of sudo java -version to no success. Side note: I've been following this tutorial https://wiki.amahi.org/index.php/McMyAdmin and I am unable to resolve any host name I try to connect to.

Comment: is the file named "java" is in there? Is the executable bit set? Maybe it is still in /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/ ?

Comment: too new to linux to be able to just check that but I have winscp connected and the /usr/bin directory has "java", "javac", "javaws" all with rwxrwxrwx for the rights.

Comment: when I run ls from that directory it shows up red if that matters

Comment: The x is what you need to ensure the file is executable. The colour scheme may be different from one distro to another so I can't say for sure. Try running java without sudo as if you run things using sudo - it may ends up trying to find program under /usr/sbin. If you need to run java with sudo, try running it with `sudo /usr/bin/java` or if you are already in /usr/bin then try `sudo ./java` - assuming java existed there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48248/discussion-between-uberaffe-and-darius).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Darius for helping me trouble shoot this!

The solution/ issue for me was that the path I set up with sudo update-alternatives --install was not pointing at the same folder that the actual files were in.

So for anyone else with a similar issue, double and triple check your file locations and path names!